# Is webmatrix appropriate for a "private" web app?

Tags: webmatrix

I would like to build a web interface for an app I build for a client. The app itself is made with Access for the front-end, and SQL Server for the database.
The idea is to allow them to check the stock of an item, or see the orders of a client using a laptop or even a smartphone, while on the road.
I have a basic experience with html and CSS, since I made a few simple sites.
My question is: would webmatrix be a good choice for that job ?
Since I master VBA and SQL quite well, and the client is a MS environment anyway, I thought webmatrix could be an easy path for that project.
Any feedback appreciated. Other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a very similar environment.  We have a legacy application developed in Microsoft Access running against SQL Server 2005.  Initially we developed a single page website using WebMatrix that had some key data displayed on it.  Over time, it's grown to having maybe 30 pages, with both employees and customers logging in to it.  It's my plan to gradually replace the Access application completely with a WebMatrix application.

Generally, the WebMatrix development enviromnent is quite competent for simple pages and I like its lightweight quick-to-boot easy-to-use approach.  On some of the more complicated pages that use c# classes, I will switch to Visual Studio.

Since you have some experience with HTML and CSS, then I think the razor syntax that WebMatrix uses is a natural progression.  If your only language experience has been vba, you might have some challenge using c# or perhaps vb.net.  I would recommend c# as being more of an standard.

Good luck!